# C++ backward regex search

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I need to build an ultra-efficient log parser (~1GB/s). I implemented Hyperscan library (https://www.hyperscan.io) from Intel, and it works well to:

- count a number of occurence of specified events
- give the end position of the matches

One of the limitation is that no capture groups can be reported, only end offsets. For most matches, I only use the count, but for 10% of them, the match must be parsed to compute further statistics.

The challenge is to efficiently run a regex to get the Hyperscan match, knowing only the end offset. Currently, I tried:

```
string data(const string * block) const {
   std::regex nlexpr("\n(.*)\n$");
   std::smatch match;
   std::regex_search((*block).begin(), (*block).begin() + end, match, nlexpr);
   return match[1];
}
```

- `block` points to the file loaded in memory (2GB, so no copy possible).
- `end` is the known offset matching the regex.

But it is extremely inefficient when the string to match is far in the block. I would have expected the "$" to make the operation very quick as the  offset is given as end position, but it is definitely not. The operation take ~1s if `end = 100000000`.

It is possible to get the start of the matches from Hyperscan, however performance impact is very high (approximately divided per 2 after testing), so that is not an option.

Any idea how to achieve this ? I am using C++ 11 (so std implements the boost regex).

Best regards

**Edit :**
As the question came in the comments, I do not have any control over the regexs to be used.

Comment: Do you have to use a `std::regex` specifically? What if you implemented the text-matching algorithm as a native C++ function? (does Hyperscan support native code execution or does it only support regex?)

Comment: Ideally I would prefer implementing regex because maintainability would be easier.   Approximately 50 regex will be run through Hyperscan. In fact I simplified the example a bit, because the match to recover may be multiline also, it is not specifically "\n(.*)\n$". As far as I know, Hyperscan does not support native code execution.

Comment: What that regex is supposed to match? everything between two newlines?

Comment: Hyperscan is a multiple regex matching library, in practice the regex can be anything. I mentioned the line example to simplify a little bit the scope.

Comment: We should know the exact regex being used and what it is supposed to match.

Comment: It is not possible in that case, regex will be user inputs and will depends on the statistics to be generated. Have a look at Hyperscan if you want to understand the concept. Basically when a regex matches in Hyperscan, Hyperscan reports which regex matched, and the end offset only. The goal is to capture the data by reexecuting the regex that matched, knowing the end position of the match.

Comment: if you can put an upper bound on the number of lines preceeding your end, say your match is always less then N lines, you could search back from 'end' with a simple loop to find N lines worth of data, and use this position as as a begin position for the regex search. This should greatly reduce the regex effort.

Comment: Could you parallelize this to speed up the search? Or is memory throughout the bottle neck?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, the software is intended to be run on end-users PC (with PCIe SSD storage) with 8GB RAM. But the bottle neck is more on the CPU cycles, so parallelism should help. rmawaston, unfortunately I cannot set an upper bound because it is file dependent but it can be one concession if I have no solution.

Comment: And you only want to return the first match? That matters.

Comment: Yes only the first match. I was thinking of using reverse iterator and regex swap function but I am unsure it can be done with the std regex templates.

Comment: In theory, you should be able to run a compiled regex backwards, but few regex packages offer this possibility. RE2 actually implements the feature internally as an optimisation but does not export it. The MS regex library apoears to offer a RightToLeft flag, but that might not help you much.

Answer (score 3):

I have not enough reputation to comment XD. I don't see the following as an answer, its more an alternative, nevertheless I have to make an answer, else I won't reach you.

I guess you won't find a trick to make performance independent of the position (guess its going linear for such simple regex or whatever).

A very simple solution is to replace this horrible regex lib with e.g. the posix regex.h (old but gold ;) or boost regex.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <regex.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
inline auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
inline auto toMs = [](auto &&x){
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(x).count();
};

void cregex(std::string const&s, std::string const&p)
{
    auto start = now();
    regex_t r;
    regcomp(&r,p.data(),REG_EXTENDED);
    std::vector<regmatch_t> m(r.re_nsub+1);
    regexec(&r,s.data(),m.size(),m.data(),0);
    regfree(&r);
    std::cout << toMs(now()-start) << "ms " << std::string{s.cbegin()+m[1].rm_so,s.cbegin()+m[1].rm_eo} << std::endl;
}

void cxxregex(std::string const&s, std::string const&p)
{
    using namespace std;
    auto start = now();
    regex r(p.data(),regex::extended);
    smatch m;
    regex_search(s.begin(),s.end(),m,r);
    std::cout << toMs(now()-start) << "ms " << m[1] << std::endl;
}
void boostregex(std::string const&s, std::string const&p)
{
    using namespace boost;
    auto start = now();
    regex r(p.data(),regex::extended);
    smatch m;
    regex_search(s.begin(),s.end(),m,r);
    std::cout << toMs(now()-start) << "ms " << m[1] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s(100000000,'x');
    std::string s1 = "yolo" + s;
    std::string s2 = s + "yolo";
    std::cout << "yolo + ... -> cregex "; cregex(s1,"^(yolo)");
    std::cout << "yolo + ... -> cxxregex "; cxxregex(s1,"^(yolo)");
    std::cout << "yolo + ... -> boostregex "; boostregex(s1,"^(yolo)");
    std::cout << "... + yolo -> cregex "; cregex(s2,"(yolo)$");
    std::cout << "... + yolo -> cxxregex "; cxxregex(s2,"(yolo)$");
    std::cout << "... + yolo -> boostregex "; boostregex(s2,"(yolo)$");
}
```

Gives:

```
yolo + ... -> cregex 5ms yolo
yolo + ... -> cxxregex 0ms yolo
yolo + ... -> boostregex 0ms yolo
... + yolo -> cregex 69ms yolo
... + yolo -> cxxregex 2594ms yolo
... + yolo -> boostregex 62ms yolo
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! Did you compile it for C++11 ? I thought that POSIX was slower than std::regex (which is a partial implementation of boost::regex since C+11) according to https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/regex/doc/vc71-performance.html

Comment: No I compiled it with c++17, but i think its not too difficult to change it to c++11 (I leave it up to you) ... I see, seems like boost is telling us that boost performs best ;).

Comment: It's true that their testing might be a bit biased. From your testing, looks like when the match is at the end, POSIX perform better, I will give it a try.

Comment: I have included boost now, performs actually quite well, similar to posix for this easy test case. It seems like only this c++11 regex lib has problems with matches at the far end. Btw i know that the c++11 regex lib has additionally a lot of bugs, which boost regex or posix has not, so its in my eyes really a horrible lib as I mentioned also in the original comment above :D.

Comment: Interesting... under VS2017 v15.6  I got 767ms for C++regex and 107ms for boost regex. Much smaller difference! Boost 1.67.0 and 64 bit build

Comment: Hmm the difference seems really a bit low, maybe you forgot optimization -O2? Further I am on Ubuntu gcc,  have a static boost build here and so on so its quite difficult to compare. If you are really motivated, you could copy paste it, go to https://wandbox.org/, turn on optimization and make a benchmark over the compilers and boost versions. But yeah its a factor >10 on https://wandbox.org/ too.

Answer (score 1):

### I just realized...

That my solutions proposed below does not work. Well, at least if there are multiple "yolo" in the text. It does not return the "first instance found in the string", but it returns the "first instance found in a substring of the string". So if you have 4 CPUs, the string is split into 4 substrings. The first to return "yolo" 'wins'. This might be OK if you only want to see if "yolo" is anywhere in the text, but not if you want to get the position of the first instance.

### Old answer

Building on OZ's answer, I've written a parallel version. edit: now using semaphores to finish early.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
std::mutex g_mtx;
std::condition_variable g_cv;
int g_found_at = -1;

void thread(
    int id,
    std::string::const_iterator begin,
    std::string::const_iterator end,
    const boost::regex& r,
    boost::smatch* const m)
{
    boost::smatch m_i;
    if (regex_search(begin, end, m_i, r))
    {
        *m = m_i;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(g_mtx);
        g_found_at = id;
        lk.unlock();
        g_cv.notify_one();
    }
}
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
void boostparregex(std::string const &s, std::string const &p)
{
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(g_mtx);
        g_found_at = -1;
    }
    auto nrOfCpus = std::thread::hardware_concurrency() / 2;
    std::cout << "(Nr of CPUs: " << nrOfCpus << ") ";
    auto start = steady_clock::now();
    boost::regex r(p.data(), boost::regex::extended);
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<boost::smatch>> m; m.reserve(nrOfCpus);
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(m), nrOfCpus, []() { return std::make_shared<boost::smatch>(); });
    std::vector<std::thread> t; t.reserve(nrOfCpus);
    auto sizePerThread = s.length() / nrOfCpus;
    for (size_t tId = 0; tId < nrOfCpus; tId++) {
        auto begin = s.begin() + (tId * sizePerThread);
        auto end = tId == nrOfCpus - 1 ? s.end() : s.begin() + ((tId + 1) * sizePerThread) - 1;
        t.push_back(std::thread(thread, (int)tId, begin, end, r, m[tId].get()));
    }
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(g_mtx);
        g_cv.wait_for(lk, 10s, []() { return g_found_at >= 0; });
    }
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(g_mtx);
        if (g_found_at < 0) std::cout << "Not found! "; else std::cout << m[g_found_at]->str() << " ";
    }
    std::cout << toMs(steady_clock::now() - start) << "ms " << std::endl;
    for (auto& thr : t) thr.join();
}
```

Which gives me this output (don't have posix under vs2017)

```
yolo + ... -> cxxregex 0ms yolo
yolo + ... -> boostregex 1ms yolo
yolo + ... -> boostparregex (Nr of CPUs: 4) yolo 13ms
... + yolo -> cxxregex 5014ms yolo
... + yolo -> boostregex 837ms yolo
... + yolo -> boostparregex (Nr of CPUs: 4) yolo 222ms
```

I get an up to 4 times speedup on 4 CPUs. There is some overhead for starting up the threads

p.s. this is my first C++ thread program and first regex, so there could be some optimizations possible.